# Are Data Extensions Called Custom Objects in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

Are Data Extensions Called Custom Objects in Salesforce Marketing Cloud when logged into the dashboard of exacttargetapis.com?

[image]

Comment: To Retrieve Custom Objects using API Calls mean retrieving the data extensions ?

Comment: What dashboard? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @zuzannamj I have added the picture to the question

Comment: where do you see "custom object"?

Comment: I meant to add a screenshot of the "dashboard of exacttargetapis.com" - I have no idea what you're referring to. The API name of the Data Extension object is simply `DataExtension`: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm?gclid=CjwKCAjwsan5BRAOEiwALzomX3UUhlI8S6zO_iO32RJ6QIZfJsWmu_CaEhr7OKju6IOh42Kw58LV4RoCQVEQAvD_BwE

Comment: @LukasLunow, I am not sure of what exactly are custom objects in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. Everytime I try to get more information it lands up in the page   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_objectcreate_task_parent.htm&type=5  which isn't relevant

Comment: @zuzannamj, I have updated the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up clouds.

Whenever you need to create a new table for storing data, you will do either of these tasks:

- In Marketing Cloud: create a new [Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_data_extension_classic.htm&type=5)
- In Sales Cloud: create a new [Custom Object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_objectcreate_task_parent.htm&type=5)

They both hold rows of data, can consist of a number of columns, and can have records written or updated via API. The key difference is, which cloud you are working with.

Comment: oh, got it now. Few members who were common with salesforce usage called it custom objects and few were calling it as Data Extensions which I couldn't relate.
This cleared my doubt. 
Thanks